# React Router Adds URL Query Params on POST Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, axios

Hello my fellow nerds,

I am running into an issue where when I make a POST request (using **Axios** library inside of **React** function), it automatically appends all of the data from the "Create a User" form into search parameters in the URL of the page upon submission. I don't like this because I'd rather this stay hidden within the POST request, not flung out onto the page URL.

Image: [URL after user was created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akz8E.png)

This is a direct result of **React Router** adding the data sent in the request of the body being appended to the location.search of react router's history object. So, naturally, since the react router history object is mutable, I tried adding this to the response of the submission:

```
this.props.location.search.replace({*some random parameter stuff here*});
```

This was in hopes it would remove all of that stuff from the URL and redirect to the page without search parameters. Anyways, I have seen a few other posts similar in nature but they don't seem to answer this exact question.

**TL;DR**: I am trying to send a POST request without React Router adding my req.body data to the params in my URL and the location.search object.

### **MY CODE:**

*Users.js*: (front end)

```
handleSubmit (e) {
    Axios.post(`${server}/s/admin/users/create`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            email: this.state.email
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

*users.js*: (back end)

```
app.post("/s/admin/users/create", (req, res) => {
let rb = req.body.data;
let newUser = new User({
    _id: uid.time(),
    orgID: req.session.orgID,
    email: rb.email,
    username: rb.username,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(rb.password, hashRate),
    firstName: rb.firstName,
    lastName: rb.lastName,
    data: { exist: "true" },
    settings: { exist: "true" }
});

// Save new owner to db
newUser.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    res.json({info: `A new user, ${newUser.firstName} ${newUser.lastName}, has been created successfully.`});
});
```

});

Thank you!

P.S. This is my first post, thank you for your patience. I've tried searching and solving this issue for about a day now.

Comment: Can you share where your component code where form part has written?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try rewriting it this way? cause axios.post expect

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: `${server}/s/admin/users/create`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    lastName: this.state.lastName,
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
    email: this.state.email
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Axios.post method expect the second argument as data but you have passed config, another way is to pass data and config in the third argument.

```js
handleSubmit(e) {
  Axios.post(`${server}/s/admin/users/create`, {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      email: this.state.email
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```